# Frigidaire Refrigerator water dispenser water flow too strong

Tags: refrigerator, water-pressure

Frigidaire Refrigerator model FRS6LR5EM8 water dispenser water flow too strong! most online items refer to low or no water pleasure. I am not sure if replacing the water inlet valve will correct this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce flow to the fridge by tightening the valve that supplies it. Trace the water line from the back of your fridge to your plumbing. If you find a valve that looks like this:

[image: multi-turn valve]

you can simply turn it clockwise a bit to restrict the flow. If you find a saddle valve like this:

[image: saddle valve]

then you will not have much ability to adjust flow at the valve. Your best bet then would be to replace the saddle valve with a proper tee and new valve with a compression outlet. While normally I'd recommend ball valves (sometimes called quarter-turn valves) for durability, they are not great for limiting flow, so here a multi-turn valve would be better.